# The usage of goes to

Tags: word-usage, verbs

```
The hungry python goes to the farm.
```

What is wrong with this sentence? I tried using a proofreading online tool and it marked the `goes to` as general wording issue. I can't really understand it but should it be replaced with something like `slithers to` which is more synchronize with the characteristic of a snake?

Comment: Are you talking about grammar or logic? Grammatically, there’s nothing wrong with the sentence; what makes you think something must be wrong with it? Is it from a school assignment? Logically, it’s a strange sentence. When have you last seen a snake go to a farm? _Go to_ implies a deliberate destination, and beyond more or less instinctive movement (like hunting prey or migrating), most animals don’t really do deliberate destinations.

Comment: Online proofreading tools are far from perfect. "Goes to" is fine, although the sentence sounds like something out of a children's book. If that's what you're going for, I say keep it in. (Also, ask other humans to proofread.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: ***The drunkard goes to the pub*** - deliberately / willingly. But if ***the worm goes to the early bird***, it certainly doesn't do *that* willingly! :)

Comment: @Fumble That’s a different meaning of _go to_, though, related to winning/obtaining, rather than movement; similarly, ***the Oscar goes to [insert name of generic Hollywood actor]***, even though the wee statuette is quite incapable of going anywhere under its own steam.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: But as you said yourself, OP's example is a strange sentence. Strange enough for me to reasonably assume that *either* sense might be intended. But there's nothing *intrinsically* wrong with the utterance, whichever meaning it's supposed to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh heh. Go to, let us go down and confound their language.

http://bibleq.net/answer/1285/

A little more seriously. :)

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/goes%20to

The grammar check program may have insufficient meanings listed for "goes to." For example, it may have something like "goes to school" meaning attends school. So it has misconstrued your sentence as indicating the python attends the farm.

I would not change that part of the sentence.